# Is there an out-of-universe reason for the cartoon sequences in S3E19?

Tags: fringe

In [Lysergic Acid Diethylamide](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Lysergic_Acid_Diethylamide), a large portion of the episode is animated.  In-universe, this is explained as being part of the confusion surrounding the particular environment in which those scenes take place.

However, I'm compelled to wonder if there's an out-of-universe explanation for this - one which centers around the actors and/or the production of the episode.  The reason I think this is because the cartoon portion seems to quite particularly begin and end with William Bell's (or, more to the point, Leonard Nimoy's) presence in the episode.

So, was there actually another reason for this - either mentioned in cast commentary or interviews?  Or was this simply an unusual exercise of artistic license?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Actor Leonard Nimoy [had retired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Nimoy#Retirement) shortly before that episode, and didn't want to go back on it, so the character of William Bell would otherwise have to have been written out.  Instead, voice-acting the animated version of Bell was used as a compromise.

He seems to have since partially gone back on the retirement, however, since he does later reprise his role as William Bell.

Comment: I just saw this episode for the first time recently, and wondered whether they may have chosen animation because live-action shooting and/or CGI with an airship was going to be too difficult and/or expensive to pull off, but this is a far more logical explanation.